# How do I pronounce Emacs?

Tags: learning

I struggle to pronounce many computer terms, and to this day still mispronounce latex in my head - it just sounds better rhyming with flex.

How would I pronounce Emacs?

Comment: Don't worry about LaTeX everyone pronounce it as it pleases them. It adds to the mystery and charm of LaTeX!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just think of E-max. The letter E is pronounced like the name of the letter is pronounced.

I has the same sound as in need, clean, feel, green etc.

Also, I recommend this video:

[How to Say or Pronounce Emacs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FW8hqLCEOJI)

Comment: Not sure I'd trust How to Say Words as it's well-established to be a joke YouTube account... but in this case it is correct.